# Landau levels from non-integrable phases?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

In general we have,
$$-i\hbar \partial_x  \psi(r) = e^{-i\frac{e}{\hbar c}\int dr 
\cdot A(r)} \left(-i\hbar \partial_x - \frac{e}{c} A_x(r) \right) \psi^\prime(r),\tag{1} $$
with,
$$\psi^\prime(r) = e^{i\frac{e}{\hbar c}\int dr 
\cdot A(r)} \psi(r). \tag{2} \quad$$

Here I'm assuming that the phase of $\psi(r)$ is single valued everywhere in space. The above should be true whether or not $\nabla\times A$ is zero. Of course when $\nabla \times A$ is non zero the phase of $\psi^\prime (r)$ become non integrable.

I'll break my questions into two parts.

(1) Suppose $\psi(r)$ satisfy the free particle wave equation. Then $\psi^\prime (r)$ should satisfy the wave equation for any magnetic field configuration such that $\nabla \times A = B$. Is this true? It seems to me that this should hold even for non-zero magnetic fields.

(2) If the above is true, suppose we solve the equation in a uniform magnetic field. How would one recover the Landau levels from $\psi^\prime (r)$?

Answer (score 1):

I get why I was confused now. In hindsight it seems obvious. But so is every thing I guess. Anyway here's what's wrong.

It's true that if one defines
$$\psi^\prime( \pmb r) = \exp\left[\frac{ie}{\hbar c}\int d\pmb r \cdot \pmb A(\pmb r) \right] 
\psi(\pmb r), \tag{1} $$
then
$$\left(-i\hbar \partial_x - \frac{e}{c} \pmb A_x(\pmb r) \right)\psi^\prime(\pmb r) = \exp\left[\frac{ie}{\hbar c}\int d\pmb r \cdot \pmb A(\pmb r) \right] (-i\hbar \partial_x) \psi(\pmb r), \tag{2}  $$
even if $\pmb \nabla \times \pmb A \neq 0 $.
This directly imply that if $\psi(\pmb r)$ solves the Schrodinger equation with no fields, then $\psi^\prime(\pmb r)$ satisfy the wave equation with fields $\pmb A(\pmb r)$.

### The wrong way I was thinking about the problem

If I chose $\psi(\pmb r)$ to satisfy the free wave equation, then I can get a solution to the Schrodinger equation with non-zero fields by just multiplying $\psi(\pmb r) $ by the phase factor $\exp\left[\frac{ie}{\hbar c}\int d\pmb r \cdot \pmb A(\pmb r) \right] $. Now since the free wave solution has a continuous spectrum this cannot be right because we know about Landau levels for example.

### The right way to think about this

The above mathematical reasoning is correct, but the physical interpretation of it is wrong.  It's instructive to rewrite Eq. (2) as,
$$-i\hbar \partial_x \psi^\prime(\pmb r) = \exp\left[\frac{ie}{\hbar c}\int d\pmb r \cdot \pmb A(\pmb r) \right] \left(-i\hbar \partial_x + \frac{e}{c}  \pmb A_x(\pmb r) \right) \psi(\pmb r). \tag{3}  $$
While this is just a trivial rearrangement of terms, it's easier to physically interpret. Now let's choose $\psi^\prime (\pmb r)$ to satisfy the free wave equation, this means that $\psi(\pmb r)$ satisfy wave equation with non-zero fields. The physical interpretation of this is that even though $\psi^\prime (\pmb r)$ satisfy the free wave equation, the non integrable phase it has mean that there must be fields that are causing this non integrability. Said in another words, we can take the effect of the fields **either** as a non integrable phase of the wave function or as the shift of the momentum in the wave equation, but not both!

My confusion was that I was accounting for the fields both in the wave equation, and then again (but with opposite sign) as a non integrable phase. No surprise then I would end up with a solution that represents a particle in no fields at all.